# How to use date and dateFormatter in a list?

Tags: swift, date, mvvm, swiftui, dateformatter

Im trying to make a simple app that when the "Add" button is pressed, it adds a new cell to the list with the title and the date it was created. Im creating this practice app using mvvm but I cant figure out how to use date and dateFormatter properly. The following code is what I have:

The model:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var createdAt = Date()
    
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Model]()
}
```

And the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static var DateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = self.DateFormatter
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack {
                        Text(self.viewModel.items[index].title)
                        Text(self.viewModel.items[index].createdAt)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Practice")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: makeNew) {
                Text("Add")
            })
        }
    }
    
    func makeNew() {
        withAnimation {
            viewModel.items.append(Model(title: "New Item \(viewModel.items.count + 1)", createdAt: Date()))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is Swift naming convention to start your properties with a lowercase letter.

Second you need to fix your date formatter declaration:

```
static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = { 
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
```

Then you call your ContentView static property `ContentView.dateFormatter.string(from: yourdate)`. In your case:

```
Text(ContentView.dateFormatter.string(from: self.viewModel.items[index].createdAt))
```